# Joi not accepting correct string value with valid ()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, joi

I have a form with a dropdown input, so the options for that input are already set.

The problem is that the value of the input, despite being correct and it is within the accepted values of the schema I got the message that `Provider must be one of [[object Set], [object Set]]`.

Most weird thing is that this problem is ocurring in production, but in `localhost` I don't get this validation error.

`provider` key from the `schema`:

```
 provider: Joi.string().required().label('Provider').when('entitlementType', {
    is: 'Offer', 
    then: Joi.string().valid(...providersForSubscriptions),
    otherwise: Joi.string().valid(...providersForProducts),
  }),
```

`providersForSubscriptions` array:

```
[
    "RBL",
]
```

`providersForProducts` array:

```
[
    "RBL",
    "content-store",
    "zencore",
    "VIP"
]
```

As you can see is a quite simple validation, it will receive some `provider` value and will accept the value if it's within the `valid` arrays.

Loging the form in the browser.

`console.log(entitlementType, provider, providersForProducts);`

And this is the output:

[image]

So what's going on? If we check the `context` from the validation warning, the input value is `zencore` and `zencore` is considered as a valid value.

Any thoughts? Should I try refactoring the schema? Why this is prod only?

Answer (score 0):

From your schema:

```js
provider: Joi.string().required().label('Provider').when('entitlementType', {
    is: 'Offer', 
    then: Joi.string().valid(...providersForSubscriptions),
    otherwise: Joi.string().valid(...providersForProducts),
  }),
```

And your output, we can see that `entitlementType` is NOT offer. So that means

```js
Joi.string().valid(...providersForProducts),
```

is being used for validation on this particular field.

We can also see the error `Provider must be one of [[object Set], [object Set]]` which means that Joi is checking against an array of sets.

That points us to `providersForProducts` as the culprit.

Why is it an array of sets? Who knows. Log that value to confirm and then work your way back to see why it's set as such.

Comment: I'm simplifying  `providerForProducts` array but actually that array comes from an imported `static` property of a class `static keyProvider = Object.freeze({ contentStore: 'content-store', rbl: 'RBL', xchange: 'xchange', zencore: 'zencore', vip: 'VIP' });`

Comment: Actually if a check with `_.isArrray(providersForProducts)` I get true. So I don't know why it's checking against an array of sets lol.